# SQL Combine and/or Join two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to compute the median from two columns from the same view, I'll call the columns `PtA` and `PtC`.  Because of the nature of the data, when `PtA` is `NULL`, the rows should not be included in the median calculation.  However, this is **not** the case for `PtC`, as this column is never `NULL`.  When both `PtA` and `PtC` are `NOT NULL`, they should be joined.  However, if `PtA` is `NULL` but `PtC` is `NOT NULL`, the field should display `PtC`, but have a `NULL` value inserted in the `PtA` column.

I'm having some difficulty understanding the theory behind this execution.  I currently use a `WITH` statement to get two tables that have all the `PtA` related data in one table, and all the `PtC` data in another.

When I `UNION ALL` on the `PtA`- and `PtC`-related tables, this captures all of the data, but obviously without joining the fields that should be.  Is there a way to "join/merge" this data as constrained above?

When I `JOIN` the tables, any `PtC` related entry that is not present in the `PtA` table will be absent, as there is no id on which to properly join the tables that captures the full breadth of the data.

EDIT: Efficiency aside, is there simply a way to `JOIN` the relevant data that is captured in the `UNION ALL`, as that result table contains all of the data, while still keeping all the `PtC` data not present in `PtA`?

EDIT:
Here is a tabular idea of what the situation/outcome is/should look like.

```
UNION ALL Result                
DepartmentName  MonthNumber CallType    PtAMedian   PtCMedian
Place 1         2           Type 1      8           NULL
Place 2         2           Type 2      NULL        9
Place 1         2           Type 1      NULL        54

Ideal Outcome               
DepartmentName  MonthNumber CallType    PtAMedian   PtCMedian
Place 1         2           Type 1      8           54
Place 2         2           Type 2      NULL        9

------

PtA (in this case)
DepartmentName  MonthNumber CallType    PtAMedian   PtCMedian
Place 1         2           Type 1      8           NULL

PtC (in this case)
DepartmentName  MonthNumber CallType    PtAMedian   PtCMedian
Place 2         2           Type 2      NULL        9
Place 1         2           Type 1      NULL        54
```

The `UNION ALL` layer has the `SELECT` statements that are actually calculating the medians.  Here is that statement:

```
SELECT
DepartmentName,
MonthNumber,
CallType,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), SUM(PtA) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), COUNT(PtA))) AS     PtAMedian,
NULL AS PtCMedian
FROM
rawDataPtA
WHERE
RowNumberASC IN (RowNumberDESC, RowNumberDESC - 1, RowNumberDESC + 1)
GROUP BY DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType

UNION ALL

SELECT
DepartmentName,
MonthNumber,
CallType,
NULL AS PtAMedian,
CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), SUM(PtC) / CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), COUNT(PtC))) AS PtCMedian
FROM
rawDataPtC
WHERE
RowNumberASC IN (RowNumberDESC, RowNumberDESC - 1, RowNumberDESC + 1)
GROUP BY DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType
```

**EDIT:**
`rawDataPtA` is the table with all of the rows of data and all of the `NULL` values removed, while `rawDataPtC` is a similar table without such modification, as `PtC` cannot be `NULL`.

EDIT:
Here are `rawDataPtA` and `rawDataPtC`:

```
WITH rawDataPtA AS (
SELECT
    DepartmentName,
    MonthNumber,
    CallType,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType ORDER BY PtA ASC) AS RowNumberASC,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType ORDER BY PtA DESC) AS RowNumberDESC,
    PtA
FROM
    rawExract
WHERE
    PtA IS NOT NULL
), rawDataPtC AS (
SELECT
    DepartmentName,
    MonthNumber,
    CallType,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType ORDER BY PtC ASC) AS RowNumberASC,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType ORDER BY PtC DESC) AS RowNumberDESC,
    PtC
FROM
    rawExract
)
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample data that is relevant to the cases you describe? also we cant do much without knowing your table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't union your tables, Left Join from the PtaC to PtaA views:

```
Select DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType, PtCMedian, PtAMedian
From PtCView
LEFT JOIN PtAView ON
      PtCView.departmentName = PtAView.departmentName AND
      PtCView.MonthNumber = PtAView.MonthNumber AND
      PtCView.CallType = PtAView.CallType
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting confused with your language. You say, "...when PtA is NULL, the **rows** should not be included in the median calculation." The entire row should be excluded or just the PtA field? Then you say, "When both PtA and PtC are NOT NULL, they should be joined." Joined? Joined how? Also you say "mean" but the column alias says "median" and the calculation you show is taking the average by month.

Here are two queries, one gives the average of PtA across the number of instances where Pta is NOT NULL. Any NULLs are ignored, which is the normal behavior of the `AVG` function. The other gives the average across all rows, taking NULLs as zeros. Which one is the one you want depends on how you really want to treat NULLs.

```
SELECT  DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType, ( PtA ) as PtA_Avg, Avg( PtC) as PtC_Avg
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType;

SELECT  DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType, Avg( IsNull( PtA, 0 ) ) as PtA_Avg, Avg( PtC) as PtC_Avg
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY DepartmentName, MonthNumber, CallType;
```

Here's a <kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37fe7/1/0)</kbd> with some sample data showing both results.